# Can class object attributes call methods that return a value that the attribute should have in C++?

Tags: c++, class

Why can't I simply call a class object attribute (i.e. `sum`) that calls a calls method (i.e. `calculateSum()`) that returns the value that attribute should have? What am I overlooking here? I know about how getter and setter functions are usually used, but I like the shortcut of simply calling an attribute that gets then itself updated with a method?

#### Entity.h:

```cpp
class Entity {
public:
  Entity(int x, int y);
  ~Entity();

  int x, y;
  int sum = calculateSum();

private:
  int calculateSum();
};
```

#### Entity.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(int x, int y) {
  this->x = x;
  this->y = y;
}

Entity::~Entity() {

}

int Entity::calculateSum() {
  return x + y;
}
```

#### main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Entity.h"

int main() {
  entity = Entity(5, 7);
  std::cout << entity.sum << std::endl; // outputs 0, should be 12!!
}
```

Is this even possible? Or are there any alternatives?

Thanks. :)

Comment: `entity = Entity(5, 7);` this will not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the [initialization order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Initialization_order) for class `Entity` is:

1. `x` is default-initialized to indeterminate value
2. `y` is default-initialized to indeterminate value
3. `sum` is initialized as `calculateSum()`
4. the body of the constructor is performed (`x` and `y` are assigned to the function parameters).

As you can see, when data member `sum` is initialized from `calculateSum()`, in which the data member `x` and `y` are used but they're just [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), still not get assigned as you expected in the constructor body.

You can initialize them in [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

```
Entity::Entity(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {
}
```

Then the order would be (same as the above in concept, but effect changes):

1. `x` is direct-initialized to the constructor parameter `x`
2. `y` is direct-initialized to the constructor parameter `y`
3. `sum` is initialized as `calculateSum()`
4. the body of the constructor is performed (does nothing)

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pKR0y9hgAS7xDexg)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I don't fully understand is, why the sum is not updated, after I change the value of x and/or y (e.g. `enitity.x = 8;`), and call `std::cout << entity.sum << std::endl;` again? Does it only work once at initialisation to call the method and after that the first return value is "fixed" to `sum`?

Comment: The links you provided are tremendously helpful! Thanks again. I need a workflow that enables me to get an updated `sum`, when `x` and `y` change.

Comment: @St4rb0y Yes you have to update `sum` again, manually. You might want a wrapper? [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9jVlskxDh6tMTrY6)

Answer (score 3):

C++ has no "attributes" like other languages do. The way to achieve what you want is to make `sum` a function:

```
class Entity {
public:
  Entity(int x, int y);
  ~Entity();

  int x, y;
  int sum() { return calculateSum(); }

private:
  int calculateSum();
};
```

As this is C++, there is of course a way to get something more close to what you want. That would require you to make `sum` an instance of a type that has an conversion operator to `int` that calls the `calculateSum` method to retrieve the value, though I don't think it is worth go there when you can simply make `sum` a method.

PS: As pointed out in another answer, you can get the expected output for your example, but you cannot (easily) get the correct `sum` after assigning a different value to `x` or `y` after construction.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I need to turn `sum` into a class method, I guess I can also return to get/set methods. Your answer was very helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Check std::function and lambda expressions.
But in general, you have to use () to invoke a function, like:

```
std::cout << entity.sum() << std::endl; // outputs 0, should be 12!!
```

Comment: `std::function` is for holding any kind of callable in one object (ie it uses type erasure and comes with small but non negligible overhead). There is not need for it here. One shouldn't use `std::function` whenever you need a function